# Python3.7 Traceback (most recent call last) в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Мои действия:

```
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install --user stdin
pip install --user serial
pip install --user numpy

python3.7
>>> ar2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ar2' is not defined
>>>
```

[исходники](https://github.com/Chris-Annin/AR2/raw/master/AR2%202.0%20software%20source%20files.zip)

В Windows 7 проблем не возникло в ubuntu 18.04 x64 почему то не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если 'ar2.py' - название файла, то его нужно писать на одной строчке с вызовом питона. Через пробел, а не через перевод строки.